# How can I use Ruby in SikuliX IDE?

Tags: ruby, jruby, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

According to the [documentation](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), SikuliX IDE supports `Python`, `Ruby` and `JavaScript` as scripting languages, but I'm not able to find how to switch from `Python`, which is the default.

The [section](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios.html#using-ruby) about using `Ruby` is empty and there is no mention of `Ruby in the [FAQ](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faqs).

Does anyone know how I can change the scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question, I came across the [solution](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/issues/119).

Right click on the file tab and choose `Set Type` on an empty file. (If the file is not empty it will be cleared.) A popup will be presented, allowing you to select the language.

This is not in the documentation, so I figure others may struggle to find this.